# DNS from home on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: networking, dns, raspberry-pi

I have a few questions regarding setting up a DNS from home or office. *clarification I am trying to host my own DNS*

1) I was looking at another website (sorry cant seem to relocate it) about setting up a DNS from home and they where talking about needing two computers with static IP addresses in addition to the machine hosting the web-server.

```
a) Is there another option for this?

b) If there is not another option how do I go about setting up a static IP?
```

2) I was looking into using two Raspberry Pi Zero's for the static IP DNS and an original Raspberry model B for the web-sever.

```
a) Will this even work?

b) like I asked above is there another way of doing this? (ie: software or a specific type of hardware)
```

3) Does anyone know if Time Warner Cable or Century Link even allow for at home DNS?

(what I am doing exactly: I am trying to set up a web-sever on an original Raspberry Pi model B and use two Raspberry Pi Zero's for the DNS. I plan to run a light-weight 4 to 5 page website from an office building for a small business)

Comment: If someone want to use your nameservers then they need to know where to find them. You could ask the nameserver for... oh wait. Loop.. :)  Hence the need for a static IP.

Comment: Is this a small business which has multiple public IPv4 addresses?  It is likely easier to use the DNS service of whichever registrar you register the domain name with.  Almost all provide DNS service for their registrants.

Comment: I was wanting my own DNS so i don't have to pay annual fees

Comment: You will have to pay for the website *name* regardless.  DNS service is typically thrown in at no additional charge.

Comment: i will also be hosting the website myself so if i have my own DNS It shouldn't cost me anything because I'm not going through a DNS service.

Comment: DNS is a tree-like structure, you have to pay the admin of .com/.net/.org/.whatever for a domain name. The cheapest way to do this is through a registrar (you could become a registrar yourself, but it is very cumbersome and expensive). In short: you have to pay a registrar a DNS registration fee for the domain name. As mentioned before, most registrars don't charge for the DNS hosting (what you could do with your own DNS server). Just the DNS server won't give you a domain name that everyone can access, simply because no-one is pointing to your DNS server.

Comment: There is not much research effort evident in this question. You want a *domain*, not a "DNS." **You must pay money for a domain.** No, there is no way around this unless you want to use a service like [FreeDNS](http://freedns.afraid.org) where instead of getting a domain you get a subdomain. It is like buying a piece of virtual land. If you don't want to pay for a domain, then you will not need to set up "DNS." I also bet you're using a residential ISP so you have to deal with dynamic IP. Thus, I suggest you use FreeDNS.

Comment: No. i wish to provide the domain from my location witch make me the DNS.

Answer (score 0):

To configure a static IP address on a Pi running raspian, you would edit `/etc/network/interfaces`.  As an example, if your business had the address block 210.5.5.0/24, and you wanted to use 210.5.5.10 for one of the DNS servers, you could modify the file to include the lines

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address 210.5.5.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 210.5.5.1
```

then restart networking with either `sudo service networking restart` or a power cycle.

Comment: thank you for telling me how to set up a static IP this will be helpfull in the future